# MySQL - Designing database for a simple game

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a simple browser based game.

To isolate my problem, let's presume there are 2 tables that reference each other like the following

```
Player ( p_id, p_name, inventory(multiple i_id) )
Item ( i_id, i_name )
```

The problem is with `inventory` column that is for storing multiple `i_id` of `Item` table.
First of all, I don't know if it would be a good design practice to make it hold multiple id values in a single column. Alternative is to divide into 3 tables as

```
Player ( p_id, p_name )
Item ( i_id, i_name )
Inventory ( i_id )
```

Now, `Inventory` is no more a column so can now hold multiple `i_id` but then,
how do I reference this set of inventory data to a unique player?

Like most RPG games, each player has own inventory where they can store their items and take subsequent actions.

Answer (score 3):

```
player
-----------
p_id
name

item
-----------
i_id
name

inventory
------------
p_id
i_id
```

Comment: @SeongLee no, the data seems normalized

Comment: this would be the LEAST redundant method of storing the information - assuming that the items are not unique - for instance 'dagger' could be in many players inventory.

Comment: And if you want to provide for multiple 'daggers' in an inventory, you only have to add a field to the inventory table.

Comment: correct - if you add 'Quantity' then you could have say 'GOLD" and the amount.

Answer (score 1):

Randy is correct

What he did is called Normalization.
Normalization is used to reduce redundancies.

yes pid will be same for many item Id but here you see only pId column is repeating instead of whole table for a item.

You can search in google for more info normalization in database 
or this is also a good link - http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

you can refer to the above link for more info